# Redefinition of nested Struct

Tags: c, struct, declaration

I'm working with an **asn1c** converted code, which has taken my ASN.1 code and converted it to C, with that, a whole host of complex types and `structs`have been declared. Currently, I am getting an this error:

> BACnetFaultParameter.h:125:11: error: redefinition of ‘struct
>   list_of_fault_values’ BACnetFaultParameter.h:78:11: note: originally
>   defined here

My current code looks like this (Note that these blocks of code are `.h`files that are included in a `.c` file of the same name):

```
 typedef struct BACnetFaultParameter {
    BACnetFaultParameter_PR present;
    union BACnetFaultParameter_u {
            NULL_t   none;
            struct fault_characterstring {

                    struct list_of_fault_values {
                            A_SEQUENCE_OF(CharacterString_t) list;

                            /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
                            asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
                    } list_of_fault_values;

                    /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
                    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
            } fault_characterstring;
```

and then a few lines down in the code the part where I'm being told I'm re-declaring the `struct list_of_fault_values`.

```
                 struct fault_state {

                    struct list_of_fault_values {
                            A_SEQUENCE_OF(struct BACnetPropertyStates) list;

                            /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
                            asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
                    } list_of_fault_values;
                  /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
                    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
            } fault_state;
```

what confuses me is that I have used `#ifndef` and `#define` statements around both blocks of code, and then I receive and error saying that

> "Fault state has no member named list_of_fault_values"

in the `.c` file. `list_of_fault_values` is local structure however its acting like a global, running grep didn't point me to any possible problems either. My questions are. Does anyone have any thoughts? or has anyone encountered something similar before?

here is the code with the `#ifndef` statements

```
                   struct fault_characterstring {
    #ifndef _LIST_OF_FAULT_VALUES
    #define _LIST_OF_FAULT_VALUES
            struct list_of_fault_values {
                            A_SEQUENCE_OF(CharacterString_t) list;

                            /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
                            asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
                    } list_of_fault_values;
                    #endif
             /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
                    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
            } fault_characterstring;
```

and

```
      #ifndef _LIST_OF_FAULT_PARAMETERS
    #define _LIST_OF_FAULT_PARAMETERS
                    struct list_of_fault_values {
                            A_SEQUENCE_OF(struct BACnetPropertyStates) list;

                            /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
                            asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
                    } list_of_fault_values;
                    #endif
                     /* Context for parsing across buffer boundaries */
                    asn_struct_ctx_t _asn_ctx;
            } fault_state;
```

Comment: What do your `#ifndef` statements look like?

Comment: I  added the "#ifndef" in the post question

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea using `#ifndef`, but `list_of_fault_values` still needs to be declared, even if the structure has already been declared.

To keep it simple, you can add an `#else` block before the `#endif`:

```
#ifndef HAVE_LIST_OF_FAULT_PARAMETERS // NB: you shouldn't use a leading underscore for macros
#define HAVE_LIST_OF_FAULT_PARAMETERS
    struct list_of_fault_values {
        ...
    } list_of_fault_values;
#else // just use the previous definition
    struct list_of_fault values list_of_fault_values;
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure definitions do not depend on each other. The first structure is defined when there is no name `_LIST_OF_FAULT_VALUES`. The second structure is defined when there is no name

```
_LIST_OF_FAULT_PARAMETERS
```

Nothing prevents to coexist the both definitions.

You have to define yourself either manifest constant `_LIST_OF_FAULT_VALUES` or `_LIST_OF_FAULT_PARAMETERS` before the both definitions of the structures that to select one of them.